# Dependency type in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, web

In my project I want to create a ear for dynamic web application and define dependency type as war for web part and jar for java part like

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>test.vias</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>war</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>test.vias</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Now the question is , how many type of dependecy we can define in pom.xml for dependent projects module.

Comment: can you elaborate your question, are you looking for how to manage your modules in ear?

Comment: pappu: I have two modules web module and corresponding java module, java is in dependency of web module pom.xml as I mentioned in code but this is showing as maven dependency for web module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other two dependencies that I found is:

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-embedder</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
```

Refer this: http://maven.apache.org/pom.html

Comment: Yess...i am also referring that document.And if it is useful then you can accept answer also.. ;) :)